# Do mime type intent filters work on HTTP URLs?

Tags: android, mime-types, intentfilter

There is a lot of example code about that uses an `IntentFilter` with a scheme of `"http"` and the `mimeType` set. See the answers to [Handling MIME type that is the result of a browser POST in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890926/handling-mime-type-that-is-the-result-of-a-browser-post-in-android), [Intent filter for browsing XML (specifically rss) in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589155/intent-filter-for-browsing-xml-specifically-rss-in-android), and [How to open my Android app when rss link is opened in browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901662/how-to-open-my-android-app-when-rss-link-is-opened-in-browser)

The specific use case I have is for RSS links, like those last two questions, but the RSS feeds I want to intercept do not have a path I can usefully match by `pathPattern`, and I have no control over that. I've tried using the same intent filter that was originally extracted from the Google Reader APK:

```
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/NewURL_intent_rss">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:host="*" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/xml"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/rss+xml" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/xml"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

but when I test this by clicking a link in Chrome that points to such a file, Chrome just browses to that file. I have Google Reader installed, and that doesn't respond to the intent either. If I replace the `mimeType` lines with a `pathPattern` that matches the test URL, my app receives the intent. By making HEAD requests to the server, I've verified that the Content-Type of the URL is being sent as "application/xml". The test device is a Nexus 10 on the stock ROM.

I made another test by restoring the `mimeType` filters and launching the URL from `am start` in a shell. This command, specifying only the URL,

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d http://my.test/url
```

launched the browser, but when I specified the type explicitly in this command,

```
am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -t application/xml -d http://my.test/url
```

it showed me an intent chooser for my app and Google Reader. This seems to confirm that the filter is taking effect, but Chrome is starting the intent without supplying a type, and the intent resolver isn't finding the type from the URL (the way it does for `content:` URIs), but it seems implausible that so many people could be using and recommending intent filters that can't possibly work. Does anyone have a definitive answer: what's the use of an intent filter with `<data android:scheme="http" android:mimeType="..." />`?

Answer (score 0):

According to another StackOverflow answer, the browser checks the Content-Disposition header and doesn't even check intent filters if it indicates an attachment.

Could this be the problem you're facing?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8770360/304876

Comment: The answer you link to is someone **guessing** that that's what's going on. It definitely isn't in this case: the RSS files do not come with the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.